# What is the difference between Array.function and Array.prototype.function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've found that some functions like `concat()` `push()` `every()` both exist in `Array` and `Array.prototype`(with firefox 57.0.1 console)

It's confusing since prototype methods exist in `Array`.
Additionally, where does staic method(`Array.from()`, `Array.isArray()` etc) exists in?

[image]

---

I think I've understood concepts of javascript prototype to some extent, so what I'm curious about is why prototype methods(`concat()` `push()` ...) apear both in `Array` and `Array.prototype`

Comment: @Kris no, it's not a duplicate.  Firefox really does have additional methods that are **not** part of the prototype.

Comment: Ok sorry you are right, got trapped the same way like all the upvoters from the second answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox's `Array` function appears to have additional (non-conformant) "static" methods that replicate the prototype methods except that they take the array as the first parameter instead of via the implicit `this` context.

To see those methods and properties of `Array`, use:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array)
```

In Firefox you'll (mostly) see the same list as in your first screenshot.   I haven't yet figured out why `Array.isArray` is missing in your list, but it does appear in my Firefox 57.

In Chrome you'll only see the ES6 mandated "static" methods (i.e. `Array.from`, `Array.isArray`, `Array.of`) and the standard properties.

Comment: My firefox also shows `Array.isArray` with `Object.getOwnPropertyName(Array)` however does not show with just `console.log(Array)` How about you?

Comment: @soonoo Likewise, it doesn't appear in the `console.log` output, but it does appear in the object inspector pane.   Perhaps it's a bug in the console?

Comment: Thanks but still confused ㅠㅠ

Comment: @soonoo what's the confusion?

Comment: it's not your answer, just about firefox's non-general behavior

Comment: @soonoo I've reported this as a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1423865

Comment: Some more information available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods if you think it’s worth linking in the answer.